# What does ./!$ mean in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

A noobie Linux learner here.

I created a python script and `chmod 700 filename.py`, when I was going to using `./filename.py`, my instructor came and use `./!$` to run the file.

What does the `./!$` that actually mean? I couldn't google it out. I'd greatly appreciate for a link of cheatsheet for the similar commend too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run a command with an arg  like *file some_file* then run !$,  put `./` before it and you end up with *./file_name*

Comment: `!$` refers to the last argument of the previous command. Since the previous command had only one argument `filename.py`, it holds that filename. The `./` is part of the path, same as when run as `./filename.py`.  Basically it was just a shell shortcut [of which there are many](http://www.ice2o.com/bash_quick_ref.html)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks, this answers my question. Why people intend to answer in a comment instead of an answer here? Any rules?

Comment: @Meruemu This question is not on topic at Stack Overflow, and more appropriate at http://superuser.com. If I put in an answer, it could make it more difficult to migrate or later delete the question.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Make sense, but hard for new user to know where the appropriate is. I thought overflow is for the general questions, isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It also fits here, as it's also a bash language question.

Comment: In `bash`, `!` refers to previous command. In `regex` `$` is an anchor at the end of the line while `^` is an anchor at the beginning of the line. Suppose I edited 5 files `vi file1.py file2.py file3.py file4.py file5.py` then I ran `./!^` it will be equivalent to `./file1.py` but if I run `./!$` it will be equivalent to `./file5.py`.

Comment: History substitution uses `regex`. For example you edited files `file1.py file2.py file3.py file4.py file5.py` then you want to reedit all but `file3.py` you can run `!!:s/file3.py//`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose I just ran a command `python test.py`. This was my last command I entered into the shell. However, its argument was `test.py`.

Remembering that `./` refers to the current working directory, when I type `./!$` I get the following output:

```
$ ./!$
./test.py
./test.py: line 1: import: command not found
./test.py: line 2: $'\r': command not found
./test.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'/test.py: line 3: `df = pd.DataFrame([
```

By context clues my last argument was used as the `!$`.

If I enter several arguments such as `python test.py test2.py` I get:

```
$ ./!$
./test2.py
./test2.py: line 1: import: command not found
Unable to initialize device PRN
```

Confirming my intuition.

Comment: for the sake of testing, much better to use `echo ./!$`

Comment: for the sake of testing, much better to use `./!$:p`.

Answer (score 2):

Fully agree with [Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski)'s comment.
`!$` refers to the last argument from the previous bash command.
For instance, if you type `echo hello world` then `!$` would expand to "world".

In your case, the `!$` is expanded into "filename.py". The command becomes strictly the same as above: `./filename.py`.

Comment: Why does it, "`!$` refers to the last argument from the previous bash command". Is it `!$` kind of black magic? There is no information in the internet about this  -- www.google.com/search?q=!%24&

Comment: Google is not good at finding such symbols. Try "bash bang dollar" for instance. For the second part, you can give a look on bash's documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Designators).

Comment: @Aif that's why I couldn't find anything on Google about it for a long time. Thanks!

Comment: See the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html), particularly the section on [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) and the subsection on [word designators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html). `!` is the character used for history substitution in general. `$` conventionally refers to the tail end of something.